# jQuery append li to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add images to list from array using jQuery

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul id="fistImagesList"></ul>
            </td>

            <td>
                <ul id="secondImagesList"></ul>
            </td>

            <td>
                <ul id="thirdImagesList"></ul>
            </td>

            <td>
                <ul id="fourthImagesList"></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    firstName = "";
    secondName = "";

    fillList("fistImagesList");
    fillList("secondImagesList");
    fillList("thirdImagesList");
    fillList("fourthImagesList");

    function fillList(name) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);


            $("#" + name).append(
                '<li><img src="' + imgArray[randomNumber].src + '" name="' + imgArray[randomNumber].name + '"/><li>'
                );

        }
    }

    var imgArray = new Array();

    imgArray[0] = new Image();
    imgArray[0].src = "images/earth.jpg";
    imgArray[0].name = "earth";

    imgArray[1] = new Image();
    imgArray[1].src = "images/mars.jpg";
    imgArray[1].name = "mars";


    imgArray[2] = new Image();
    imgArray[2].src = "images/saturn.jpg";
    imgArray[2].name = "saturn";


    imgArray[3] = new Image();
    imgArray[3].src = "images/jupiter.png";
    imgArray[3].name = "jupiter";
})(jQuery);
```

I googled it and saw many posts about append() and appendTo() on stackoverflow.com and on other sites, but nothing happens when browser compiles my files.

maybe I have used bad jquery selector? `$("#"+name)`. but when I using `$("table.center>tbody>tr>td>ul#"+name)` or `$("table.center>tr>td>ul#"+name)` nothing happens too.

Comment: You need to call fillList function after you assign the value to imgArray, at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Move this:

```
fillList("fistImagesList");
fillList("secondImagesList");
fillList("thirdImagesList");
fillList("fourthImagesList");
```

to the bottom of your code. When you use it on the top your `imgArray` is still empty.

Comment: Moved it, but still nothing happens

Comment: Yes I did it like this, and nothing happened

Comment: So there must be another problem. Your code with this modification seems to be ok.

Comment: I think so. Thanks for your replies. Maybe problem is in selector? `$("#"+name)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98494/discussion-between-mwl-and-dato-maisuradze).

Answer (score 0):

mwl is correct. Those functions should go below.

However, when you are not using a third party editor like jsFiddle and working locally (**this is good practice anyways**).

**You need to wrap your JS code in ready statement:**

`$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here })`

or short hand
`$(function(){ // your code here })`

or without **jQuery library**

put `<script src="main.js"></script>` after the `</body>` close tag.

Hope this helps!